# Difference between ‘Passant’ and ‘Fußgänger’

Tags: difference, noun

I am studying the difference between *Passant* and *Fußgänger.*

I have two hypotheses:

1. *Fußgänger* is a person who is walking on foot. Both *Passant* and *Fußgänger* can be used to refer to a person walking on a sidewalk.
2. *Fußgänger* is a person who is walking on foot. *Passant* can be used to refer to a person walking on a sidewalk.

(I was told these two ideas by two different natives, so I am pretty confused now)

What is the difference between then?

Answer (score 9):

Neither the word *Passant* nor the word *Fußgänger* have any intrinsic relation to a pavement. Both can be used for people on or off a pavement.

*Fußgänger*, as you correctly noted, is a person walking on foot, i.e. the nominalisation of *zu Fuß gehen.* It technically could apply to people walking on foot anywhere (in a building, on a train, in the street, in the forest …) but it is usually only used in contexts of traffic. It does *not* state that the person is walking on the pavement. It *can* be used and is used for people walking at the side of roads that don’t have pavements, walking on the middle of a road, etc.

*Passant* is a borrowing from the French verb *passer* meaning *to pass.* Thus, it does not refer to any specific mode of transport in itself, nor does it refer to a specific place of a road; it merely signifies that somebody is passing. In the overwhelming majority of cases, though, it will be somebody walking past you. However, it does *not* have to be in the context of traffic and most importantly there is *no* requirement for a pavement anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think *Passant* is closer to *passer-by* than *pedestrian*. Although a Passant will usually be on foot, I don't think it is compulsory; it is possible to imagine a cyclist or two passing by among all those pedestrians.

Perhaps a native speaker will put me right about this.

Comment: Less verbose than my answer but basically the same — needless to say, the native speaker in me agrees ;)

Answer (score 1):

Jemand, der an einem Straßencafé vorbeigeht, ist für den vorbeifahrenden Motoristen ein Füßgänger, für den Gast des Cafés jedoch ein Passant.

Comment: Warum nicht auch für den Gast des Cafés?

Comment: Weil sich Fußgänger auf einen Verkehrsteilnehmer bezieht, der kein Vehikel zur Fortbewegung nutzt. Der Gast des Cafés nimmt nicht am Straßenverkehr teil, der Motorist schon. Wenn der Gast des Cafés in einer Metaebene denkt, dann ist der Passant natürlich auch ein Fußgänger.

Answer (score 1):

To add a short definition for both terms:

> Fußgänger: A person who participates in traffic but does not use any kind of vehicle.

›Fußgänger‹ is perfectly translated to pedestrian, I guess.

> Passant: A person passing by.

Carsten's example sentence shows you how to use both terms in practice. A ›Fußgänger‹ is not solely a person walking on foot. Wheelchair users couldn't be ›Fußgänger‹, therefore.